# Protecting a Endpoints method

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to protect my endpoint. Only allow my android app use this endpoint method. How can i archive this purpose?. I don't want to ask user to provide credential.

I did provide the clientids. But look like the  User parameter on backend is always null. I'm following this instruction. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/code_walkthrough#oauth_protecting_a_method

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? I was having the same behaviour of a null User object no matter what, but it has recently and magically fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue, and soon the User object will populate properly, but for now, you can use the following workaround to get a valid User object:

```
OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
user = oauth.getCurrentUser();
```

This is based on the comment in the public issue tracker thread for a related issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8848#c15).